# C# Multi-line TextBox as floating numbers (Problems with keeping the dot in check)

Tags: c#

Today I've a question on a project I've been working on. The idea for this project is to have a TextBox based input section in which I could put my numbers in and later do some calculations with them.

[[image: Program Outline]

I've already solved the problem of ignoring any unwanted characters (Only 0 to 9, SPACE and ENTER are allowed),

But now I'm faced with the real challenge... The Dot.

Currently as it is I have the following code for it:

private void limitInputMainField(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !("\r\b .0123456789".Contains(e.KeyChar));

```
if (e.KeyChar == '.')
{
    testLines = mainField.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    try
    {
        if (testLines[testLines.Length - 1].IndexOf('.') != -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

}

This would fix the problem of inputting the dot for as long as the numerical values are proceeding forwards (By which I mean as long as the user doesn't change his/her mind and decides to go back and edit a previous value).

This then becomes a nightmare, because the code is only based on the last value entered.

Meaning if there is no Dot in the last value - then a silly amount of dots can be placed in the previous values, and/or if there is a Dot on the last value then no previous Dot can be re-placed at all.

I've tried checking them individually with for / foreach loops, however this proved to be impossible as it doesn't really tell me which value I'm about to edit and how can I check if that value already contains a Dot or not.

Thank you in advance,

Binary Life

Comment: Do not use images, copy the code inside the question. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making way too much work for yourself.  Just attempt to parse out the values in the TextChanged() event and toggle your "Process/Calculate" button based on the results so the user can only proceed when everything is good.  You can give feedback in the ListBox to let the user what numbers have been successfully parsed.  This could look something like this:

```
private bool ValidData = false;
private List<decimal> numbers = new List<decimal>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidData = true; // assume it's all good until proven otherwise
    numbers.Clear();

    decimal value;
    string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for(int i = 0; i< values.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = values[i].Trim();
        if (decimal.TryParse(values[i], out value))
        {
            numbers.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            ValidData = false;                   
        }
    }

    button1.Text = ValidData ? "Process" : "Invalid Data";
    button1.Enabled = ValidData;

    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.DataSource = numbers;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidData)
    {
        // do something with each number
        foreach(decimal value in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough, that is a genius way of looking at it without making it overly complicated and also keeping it clean and functional and most importantly safe! This solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a regular `TextBox` for user input and a `ListBox` to keep users entries?

You can simply validate user inputs with a button and edit added entries with same `TextBox`(With `ListBox` `SelectedIndexChanged` events) so you can add/edit entries easily.

Then you can loop over that ListBox items and calculate what you decided to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right Ryan, and thank you for the consideration, in fact, I have indeed done that already on a side-version of the program, and it worked very well. However, this then means that the user cannot copy and paste any list of values, and changing them around is not as user friendly anymore. It would seem that the safer the program gets the more dull and narrow the interface becomes.